# Waiting for: tcp://db:5432 Timeout after 30s waiting on dependencies to become available: [tcp://db:5432]

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, odoo, traefik

Im new with docker and odoo
trying to use odoo14 and postgresql with some dependencies in docker-compose
when i use docker logs for postgresql container the db its ready to accept the connection instead of logs of odoo container i got that issue any help please

Thank you

[image: Problem Picture]

Comment: Could you add more information. Have you an error message ? Could you add the docker-compose.yml in your first message.

Comment: Thank you jo541 i solved the problem when i reinstall docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in my system. I think this occurs because the container hasn't stopped correctly.

What worked for me was to restart Docker.

Try this command:

> sudo systemctl restart docker.socket docker.service

If it doesn't work then try to kill the 5432 port:

> sudo kill -9 5432